# How to extract specific pattern lines from multiple files AND get the file name & date modified for each line - Powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell, powershell-ise

**Summary of the process:**

There is a patching process that creates log files which all go into 1 folder and are not updated or modified again. All log files from all patches go here, and are not overwritten.

During this patching, it does multiple updates to multiple areas, but will only update the parts that have a version lower than the new update. (for example a version of 'Section.X' is 12, the patch is to make Section.X 15 <- this will update. If the patch was to make Section.X 11 it would not update.)

- When this does update update, it starts the line with 'Applying' in the .log file with some other required information (all on 1 line, all of which is needed).
- When it does not update a section, it starts with 'Not applying. I do **not** need this info currently.

**What I am trying to do:**

I am trying to Take:
- Specific lines from the .log files.
- The File name they came from .
- The modified date of the file they came from.

**Tests / Script so far:**

```
#Creating the String, and applying the filter to only take the 'Applying' lines, and then creating a new line for it to repeat.
$myString = (Select-String -Path "C:\FilePathHere\*.log" -Pattern '^Applying ').Line

# This will take the Modified date from the File.
$lastModifiedDate = (Get-Item "C:\FilePathHere\*.log").LastWriteTime

$arr = $myString -split ' '

$Groups1 = @()
$Groups = @()

#Create a table holding just the specific info from each line required, and putting that into a table.

foreach($members in $myString)
        {
            $arr = $members -split ' '

            $Groups1 = New-Object PSObject 
            $Groups1 | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name 'Object Updated' -Value $arr[1]
            $Groups1 | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name 'New Version' -Value $arr[3]
            $Groups1 | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name 'Old Version' -Value $arr[8]
            $Groups1 | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name 'Server/DB' -Value $arr[5]
            $Groups1 | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name 'Updated Date' -Value $lastModifiedDate
            $Groups += $Groups1  
        }  
# to display the recorded and ordered info:
$Groups
```

**Problems so far:**

So, the Above actually does the majority of what I want. What it does DO:
- It takes the correct lines.
- It orders it correctly.
- It only takes the required information.
- It inputs it correctly into the Excel sheet.

what it does not do is:

Put the correct Modified Date by the correct line. - At the moment, it takes the first file and states that all of the lines have the same file modified date.

**Thank you!**
Sorry for the long post, I wanted to make sure I provided all of the details required here. I appreciate any help you can provide. I am quite new to Powershell and am still trying to piece things together at the moment, Please bear with me.

Comment: would you please post a few lines from your log file - and show what your current code gets from them ... and what is NOT as intended?

Comment: Unless your file has a pattern that reveals its timestamp, you cannot dynamically figure out when a line was added to a file.

Comment: You may have better luck using a `Get-ChildItem` or `Get-Item` to find your files. Then `foreach-object` or `foreach` each of those files. That can wrap this code provided you tweak `Select-String` for the current object (a file). It may be less efficient, but you may have to sacrifice concision and efficiency to achieve your goals.

Comment: In your code, `$lastModifiedDate = (Get-Item "C:\FilePathHere\*.log").LastWriteTime` will store an array of datetimes if more than one file is returned; that is your error.  You should be iterating the files alongside the parsing if you want this context to be correct logically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you're defining $lastModifiedDate and then set it as value for 'Updated Date' causes the variable to never change, regardless of which log file $myString comes from.  I would look at each file individually so the LastWriteTime of each file keeps evolving as my table is created.  I would try this :

```
$logfiles = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\FilePathHere\*.log

$Groups1 = @()
$Groups = @()

foreach ($logfile in $logfiles) {

    $myString = (Select-String -Path "C:\FilePathHere\$($logfile.Name)" -Pattern '^Applying ').Line

    $arr = $myString -split ' '

    $lastModifiedDate = $logfile.LastWriteTime

    foreach ($members in $myString) {

        $arr = $members -split ' '

        $Groups1 = New-Object PSObject 
        $Groups1 | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name 'Object Updated' -Value $arr[1]
        $Groups1 | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name 'New Version' -Value $arr[3]
        $Groups1 | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name 'Old Version' -Value $arr[8]
        $Groups1 | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name 'Server/DB' -Value $arr[5]
        $Groups1 | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name 'Updated Date' -Value $lastModifiedDate
        $Groups += $Groups1  

    }

}

# to display the recorded and ordered info:
$Groups
```

Comment: This was bang on the money, I have added in an additional line to also return the file name for each line (where it came from). Thanks for all of the help! and that goes to everyone who left comments on this.

Comment: Since you are using `Get-ChildItem`, each `$logfile` in the loop already is a FileInfo object. To get the LastWriteTime property, you don't need to (re) `Get-Item`, simply use `$logfile.LastWriteTime`.

Comment: Indeed.  I mostly copy-pasted things around and hadn't caught this.  It's edited.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I would utilize the `-Path` parameter on the `Select-String` cmdlet to shorten the loop and output an array of PsObjects to a variable:

```
$result = Select-String -Path 'C:\FilePathHere\*.log' -Pattern '^Applying ' | ForEach-Object {
    $arr = $_.Line -split ' '
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        'Object Updated' = $arr[1]
        'New Version'    = $arr[3]
        'Old Version'    = $arr[8]
        'Server/DB'      = $arr[5]
        'LogFile'        = $_.Path
        'Updated Date'   = (Get-Item -Path $_.Path).LastWriteTime
    }
}

# output on screen
$result

# output to CSV
$result | Export-Csv -Path "D:\logInfo.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Hope that helps